# Data from Axios is coming back undefined React

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

My GET request with axios returns back undefined in my console. All of my endpoints are good and 
working from being tested with postman. My initial state go from pets: [] to pets: "". I think it's how I have my async await function set up to get the response data.
Here's the GET Component code

```
import React, {
  Component
}
from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class ListPets extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pets: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getPets();
  };

  getPets = async() => {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/pets/');
    const pets = res.data;
    this.setState({
      isLoaded: true,
      pets: pets
    });
    console.log('Data has been received!');
    console.log(pets.data)
    return pets;
  }

  render() {
    console.log('State: ', this.state);
    const {
      isLoaded,
    } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div> Loading... </div>;
    } else {
      return (<div></div>);
    }
  }
}

app.get('/pets', function(req, res){
const resultArray = [];
client.connect(err => {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const cursor = db.collection('pet').find({});
iterateFunc = (doc,err) => {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        resultArray.push(doc);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc, null, 4));
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
    }
    }
        cursor.forEach(iterateFunc);
        client.close();
        res.render('index', {pets: resultArray});

  });
```

});

Comment: What does the data look like? You are lots pets.data, is there an additional data property on the JSON body?

Comment: Okay, you may need to share the code for the server endpoint because it seems like the server may not be returning any data.

Comment: Here is the data I'm trying to render from my database


{
    "_id": "5dfe7b55a3678700785c9b69",
    "species": "Collie",
    "name": "Dax",
    "age": "2",
    "petImage": "C:\\fakepath\\brown-and-white-dog-4633734_640.jpg"
}

Comment: Is that logs out if you do console.log(res.data)? Or did you copy that from the network tab of browser developer tools? Or is that directly from the database? You need to provide more information.

Comment: I'll share the code for the server when I get home from work. The code is on my personal computer.

Comment: It's from the terminal console log from the server code in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Okay, what does console.log(res.data) log in getPets?

Comment: pets: " "  is what logs out and then Data has been received and then undefined

Comment: Okay you need to share code for your server, your endpoint has issues.

Comment: Ok I will when I get to my home computer. Thanks man

Comment: I added the server GET endpoint

Comment: I imagine the issue is that the endpoint doesn't actually send any data back so `res.data` will be empty. Did you intend to instead do `res.send({pets: resultArray});` or `res.json({pets: resultArray})` to send JSON to the React axios call? `res.render()` and `res.send()` are vastly different operations. You can't pass data to remote HTTP responses as if it was a jade/pug template.

Comment: I was following the documentation from the official website. So, I wasn't really paying attention to what I was doing closely. So would I res.send or res.json. Will either work with sending the image data also?

Answer (score 0):

Your code can only render a Loading message but if the problem is the empty string then my guess is your API is returning an empty string.

Here's your code, slightly modified but working with a JSONPlaceholder API: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-faraday-h9xpg

```
export default class ListPets extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pets: [],
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getPets();
  };

  getPets = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
    const pets = res.data;
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true, pets: pets });
  };

  render() {
    const { isLoaded, pets } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return <>{pets && pets.map(pet => <div key={pet.id}>{pet.title}</div>)}</>;
  }
}
```